# What keywords belong in method declarations in Java interfaces?

Tags: java

I'm trying to figure out what would be the best declaration valid in an interface.

Sorry, I am a beginner

```
a.  public double methoda();
b.  public final double methoda();
c.  static void methoda(double d1);
d.  protected void methoda(double d1);
```

Comment: Read from here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/interfaceDef.html

Comment: @Habib Read the JLS :D http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.4

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about us doing your exam for you.


Comment: Are you seriously just cheating on an exam as you go? It appears that way based on your other questions. What makes you think you deserve a passing grade? You appear to be a beginner to solving your own problems as well.

Answer (score 2):

`return_type method(arguments)` would be the way to do it.

---

Skip the `public abstract` because it is discouraged. According to [JLS 9.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.4):

> It is permitted, but discouraged as a matter of style, to redundantly
>   specify the public and/or abstract modifier for a method declared in
>   an interface.

Also, consistency is the key

```
public interface Foo{
  public void MakeFoo();
  void PerformBar();
}
```

In the above example, both the methods are the same `public abstract` but they are written in an inconsistent style.

So, avoid redundant modifiers in the interface.

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.4

---

1. In `public double methoda();`, the modifier `public` in redundant but ok it will compile.
2. If a method is `final` , how can it be overridden ?
3. `abstract` methods cannot be `static`. Refer JLS.
4. `protected` and `public` seem to contradict, don't they ?

Comment: +0 This is a good answer, but strongly disagree with doing homework / exam questions, see poster's other questions.

Comment: @JasonC woopsie... I did not know that. :-D